# what is required to connect SMS System to my ERP?

Tags: sms, erp

we are implementing a new ERP System, and we need later to integrate with new SMS system. 
We have existing subscription with a company for SMS text, we need now to know what is required to send SMS for example when employee confirmed for a leave.

I required only general description for that if possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If your service provider provides an HTTP API (which most providers does) then depending upon the technology stack you're using, you can make an HTTP call after confirmation event occurs.

Hope it helps.